# Using “Get Only” Static property as Binding source

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have class structures as mentioned below.

```
 //On the design aspects, I know It may not be the advisable approach, 
 //but something of this kind is only required.

/// <summary>
/// Paper Class
/// </summary>
public class Paper
{
    public string PaperName { get; set; }
    public bool IsPending { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// PaperChecking class, Individual papers will be processed here.
/// </summary>
public class PaperChecking
{

    public static List<Paper> ListPapers { get; set; }

    public static void AddPapers()
    {
        ListPapers = new List<Paper>();

        ListPapers.Add(new Paper() { PaperName = "Paper1", IsPending = false });
        ListPapers.Add(new Paper() { PaperName = "Paper2", IsPending = false });
        ListPapers.Add(new Paper() { PaperName = "Paper3", IsPending = false });
        ListPapers.Add(new Paper() { PaperName = "Paper4", IsPending = false });
        ListPapers.Add(new Paper() { PaperName = "Paper5", IsPending = false });
    }

    public static bool IsCheckingPending
    {
        get
        {
            //List has items and it is not null, so intentionally removed the checks.
            return ListPapers.Count(paper => paper.IsPending == true) > 0 ? true : false;
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// This class will select papers for processing
/// </summary>
public class ChangePaperSetting
{
    public void SelectPaper(string paperName)
    {
        //It can be assumed that Paper object will never be NULL
        PaperChecking.ListPapers.FirstOrDefault(paper => paper.PaperName.Equals(paperName)).IsPending = true;

    }
}
```

Now,
I want to use property PaperChecking.IsCheckingPending to display some controls in my WPF window. I have bound the same property with Visibility of my controls. When window loads for the first time behavior is expected because Collection is already there. But at run-time when I am changing the Pending status of Paper object as below :

```
    ChangePaperSetting changePaperSetting = new ChangePaperSetting();
    changePaperSetting.SelectPaper("Paper1");
    changePaperSetting.SelectPaper("Paper2");
    changePaperSetting.SelectPaper("Paper5");
```

In my collection, now I have papers which have IsPending as true. So now PaperChecking.IsCheckingPending will return TRUE and according to that my controls should be visible now.

In a normal object I could have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged , but in above case I do not have a Setter on the property. Is there any way of doing this or any other neat approach using same kind class structures.

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
```

Update

As suggested by Josh, I tried something like this :

```
/// <summary>
/// Paper Class
/// </summary>
public class Paper : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string PaperName { get; set; }
    private bool isPending;

    public bool IsPending
    {
        get
        {
            return isPending;
        }
        set
        {
            if (isPending != value)
            {
                isPending = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsPending"));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

/// <summary>
/// PaperChecking class, Individual papers will be processed here.
/// </summary>
public class PaperChecking : Control
{

    public static List<Paper> listOfPapers { get; set; }

    public static bool IsCheckingPending
    {
        get
        {
            //List has items and it is not null, so intentionally removed the checks.
            try
            {
                return listOfPapers.Count(paper => paper.IsPending == true) > 0 ? true : false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { return false; }
        }
    }


    public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public  static void PendingStatusChanged(object sender,PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "IsPending")
        {                
           //If I keep it static, It given Null Reference Error 
           //and If I implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface 
           //in this Class, it gives compilation error because 
           //I am doing so in my Static property.

            PropertyChanged(null,new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsCheckingPending"));
        }
    }

}

/// <summary>
/// This class will select papers for processing
/// </summary>
public class ChangePaperSetting
{
     public static void AddPapers()
    {

       var listOfPapers = new List<Paper>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var paper = new Paper() { PaperName = "Paper"+i.ToString(), 
                                      IsPending = false };
            paper.PropertyChanged+=PaperChecking.PendingStatusChanged;
            listOfPapers.Add(paper);
        }
        PaperChecking.listOfPapers = listOfPapers;
    }
    public void SelectPaper(string paperName)
    {
        //It can be assumed that Paper object will never be NULL
        PaperChecking.listOfPapers.FirstOrDefault(paper => paper.PaperName.Equals(paperName)).IsPending = true;
    }
}
```

Here is my XAML Code :

```
<Window xmlns:my="clr-namespace:LearningWpf"  x:Class="LearningWpf.Window4"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window4" Height="300" Width="300"     
    >
<Window.Resources>
    <my:PaperChecking x:Key="paperChecking"/>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="bvc" />
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <Button Name="btn1" Content="Button1" Height="20" Width="80" Click="btn1_Click"></Button>
    <Button Name="btn2" Content="Button2" Height="20" Width="80" Click="btn2_Click"></Button>
    <Button Name="btn3" Content="Button3" Height="20" Width="80" 
            Visibility="{Binding Source={StaticResource paperChecking},
                         Path=IsCheckingPending,
                         Converter={StaticResource bvc}}"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Here is my CodeBehind.cs

```
public partial class Window4 : Window
{
    public Window4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ChangePaperSetting.AddPapers();

    }

    private void btn2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var v = PaperChecking.listOfPapers.FirstOrDefault(paper => 
                 paper.PaperName == "Paper1");
        v.IsPending = true;
    }
}
```

But this code is giving error, righlty so because I am using Static variable without initializing it. If there is any correction or any other approach to achieve the same target. Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Off topic, but why are all the properties and functions within PaperChecking static?

To solve your problem though, add a new function to `PaperChecking` and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
public void SelectPaper(string paperName)
{
    var paper = ListPapers.FirstOrDefault(paper => paper.PaperName.Equals(paperName));
    if (paper != null)
    {
        paper.IsPending = true;
        PropertyChanged("IsCheckingPending");
    }
}
```

I'm assuming you know how to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and have your own way of raising the event. There is nothing that says you must raise the event from a setter of a Property.

Having your property getter cycle through your entire list of papers each time it is queried is very very inefficient. It can and will be called very very often. Pretty much with any mouse or keyboard event. You should try caching the value of the count each time the pending status is changed on a Paper. It will take a bit more work, but it might be worth doing.

Edit:

> Actually Objects can be updated from multiple interfaces and they will not call same method, they have reference to PAPER object and will update property directly, instead of calling method in PaperChecking class

In that case, you should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the Paper class, and then listen for those updates within `PaperChecking`.

```
public void PaperChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.PropertyName == 'IsPending') PropertyChanged("IsCheckingPending");
}

public void AddPapers()
{
    ListPapers = new List<Paper>();

    ListPapers.Add(new Paper() { PaperName = "Paper1", IsPending = false });
    ListPapers.Add(new Paper() { PaperName = "Paper2", IsPending = false });
    ListPapers.Add(new Paper() { PaperName = "Paper3", IsPending = false });
    ListPapers.Add(new Paper() { PaperName = "Paper4", IsPending = false });
    ListPapers.Add(new Paper() { PaperName = "Paper5", IsPending = false });
    foreach(var paper in ListPapers) 
    {
        paper.PropertyChanged += PaperChanged;
    }
}
```

You also need to transform `PaperChecking` into a class that uses instance methods and properties rather than static ones. If you don't already know about MVVM, I suggest [reading up on it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx). Essentially, what you'd do, is create an instance of `PaperChecking`, and set it as the `DataSource` in your code behind of the View. Then, in your XAML, you can simply bind like this:

```
<Button Name="btn3" Content="Button3" Height="20" Width="80" 
  Visibility="{Binding IsCheckingPending, Converter={StaticResource bvc}}" />
```

Static properties and methods are nearly always wrong when starting out with WPF. Know when you need to use them, and when you're trying to make things easier on yourself.

Comment: Actually I thought of doing that but no. of interfaces updating the property is large here and in lifetime of my object property is going to be changed very often.

Comment: Actually Objects can be updated from multiple interfaces and they will not call same method, they have reference to PAPER object and will update property directly, instead of calling method in PaperChecking class. If that would have been the case then the question is rather simple and straight implementation.

Comment: This I have to assign this handler whenever and wherever new Paper is added. But the same collection is being updated across multiple interfaces, this seems quite difficult. Is there any alternative by using dependency properties.

Comment: @ Josh: Regardin this code,                                        public static void PaperChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.PropertyName == 'IsPending') PropertyChanged("IsCheckingPending");
} I was trying to use this approach. But still Getter of my property is not being called again if any Item Property is changing.

Comment: @PanditA, have you bound the visibility property in your xaml with an appropriate converter to the correct property on your ViewModel? Can you show us an example of a control that is bound to this property please?

Comment: I have used framework provided BooleanToVisibilityConverter. BUt If I keep my property static, and tries to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, It throws a compilation error saying Static property can't implement the interface. In PAPER class, INotifyPropertyCHanged is already implemented. Now I am trying to do in PaperChecking Class...

Comment: @PanditA Then change `PaperChecking` to use instance methods and properties. If you really need to, make it a singleton, or use a dependency injection framework and make sure it's registered as a singleton.

Comment: If you have any sample or any link where I can explore more for the same pattern. Please let me know. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @PanditA there is a link to MVVM in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using CLR property, so its your duty to notify the UI that underlying binding property has changed which is only achievable by raising PropertyChanged event from your code.
First of all make the collection as `ObservableCollection` since it implements INotifyCollectionChanged and INotifyPropertyChanged. Hook the collection changed event with your collection and in handler simply raise the propertyChanged event for your property like this -

```
ObservableCollection<Paper> listOfPapers =  new ObservableCollection<Paper>();
listOfPapers.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(listOfPapers_CollectionChanged);

void listOfPapers_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
       OnPropertyChanged("IsCheckingPending");
}
```

With this approach you won't have to worry if you need to add items in the collection from method other than SelectPaper().

Other possible solution could have been use `Dependency Property` instead of plain CLR property that way you won't have to worry about raising the property changed explicitly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx

Comment: This doesn't work if changing properties on the list items, but only if you change the collection.

Comment: @RV Yeah same as Josh said, I am not changing collection here but the composing items. I was looking at the alternative using dependency property. I was trying to use that but I have question whether to use dependency property on the Paper class or PaperChecking class. If you have any reference please redirect me there. Thanx for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, maybe?

```
private static bool _isCheckingPending;
public static bool IsCheckingPending 
{ 
    get 
    {             
        bool pending = ListPapers.Count(paper => paper.IsPending == true) > 0;

        if (pending != _isCheckingPending) 
        {
           PropertyChanged("IsCheckingPending");
           _isCheckingPending = pending;
        }

        //List has items and it is not null, so intentionally removed the checks. 
        return _isCheckingPending;
    } 
}
```

The idea is that it remembers the result from last time, and if it differs from the result this time, raise the PropertyChanged event (and of course you will ave implemented INotifyPropertyChanged).

Comment: But in static property It is not allowing to implement PropertyChanged Event.Any work around.

Comment: And above all GET will be called only and only if somebody tries to access the value. Here objects in underlying collection have been changed and after that It should be called itself. That is my issue here. How underlying collection notifies that It has changed.